# changing object values with onchange handler with react hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have onChange handler but when I type it removes the lng value from the whole object

So I have an object stored in State.

```
  const [inputFields, setInputFields] = useState({
    style: "",
    coordinates: { lat: 51.501476, lng: -0.140634 },
    assetId: "",
  });
```

The onChange handler

```
  const handleLat = (event) => {
    setInputFields({ ...inputFields, coordinates: {[event.target.name]: parseInt(event.target.value)} })
  };
```

Which results in

```
{
  "style": "",
  "coordinates": {
    "lat": 23434434287
  },
  "assetId": ""
}
```

I would like to retain the "lng" value and not override the whole coordinates object.

Comment: What I understand from your question you want to update specific field. Try doing this `setInputFields(inputFields => ({ ...inputFields, coordinates: {...inputFields.coordinates,[event.target.name]: parseInt(event.target.value)} }))`

Comment: Thanks, it was making sure the previous was set

Comment: Yes because hooks are async in nature. Because of that you might not see latest changes

Comment: Brill, if you had this as an answer I'll accept. thanks

Comment: Have updated this to in answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following above thread, You can do this:

```
setInputFields(inputFields => ({ ...inputFields, coordinates: {...inputFields.coordinates,[event.target.name]: parseInt(event.target.value)} }))
```

Answer (score 1):

try following :

```
const handleLat = (event) => {
    setInputFields(
        { ...inputFields, 
            coordinates: {[event.target.name]: parseInt(event.target.value), ...inputFields.coordinates}
         })
  };
```

Comment: No that doesn't work, its not updated the state now.